# Função onClick chamando o Onclick do elemento de baixo

Tags: react, crud

Boa tarde, estou tendo um problema com meu código em react, estou fazendo um crud padrão, onde renderizo dentro de uma Ul várias LI, e cada LI possui um onClick que faz com que seja aberto um menu na tela do usuario onde ele consegue ver os detalhes do cliente, porém nessa mesma LI tenho dois botões, um botão de editar o usuario e outro de remover, quando faço o click na LI funciona normalmente Menu abre, quando dou o click no botão de remover ele chama a função de remover, remove o cliente, porém chama o Onclick da LI que estava por baixo, não tenho o codigo no momento mas vou deixar abaixo um exemplo:

```
<ul>
  <li OnClick={infosUsuarios}>
    <h1>nome do cliente</h1>
    <p>idade<p>
    <button OnClick={editarUsuario}>Editar<button>
    <button OnClick={removerUsuario}>Remover<button>
  <li>
<uL>
```

quando chamo o editar usuario ele exibe outra rota então não tenho problemas, quando click no remover usuario, ele chama a função remover usuario, e chama a função infosUsuarios, que faz com que abra esse menu, ja tentei de tudo, há uma maneira de fazer com que esse botão chame apenas a função removerUsuario e não reconhecer o OnClick da Li?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1):

Use o event.stopPropagation()

```
const editarUsuario = (e) => {
   e.stopPropagation();
   [...]
}

const removerUsuario = (e) => {
   e.stopPropagation();
   [...]
}

[...]

<ul>
  <li OnClick={infosUsuarios}>
    <h1>nome do cliente</h1>
    <p>idade<p>
    <button OnClick={(e) => editarUsuario(e)}>Editar<button>
    <button OnClick={(e) => removerUsuario(e)}>Remover<button>
  <li>
<uL>
```